# Google Maps on site HTTP/HTTPS error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, safari

I'm requesting Google Maps (latest API, *AFAIK*) on my site, but I'm getting an error in the console and some googl'n didn't do the trick.

I'm requesting the maps via
`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBQ-4VHuS8q6AzOD5g0Cbjxx1OpB3fus1w&q=Achterom+93,3311KB,Dordrecht+Nederland&zoom=13"></iframe>`

and the error is seen in the image below.
Note: "Anonieme functie" means "Anonymous function" in regular English. 
[image: Google Error]

All I can think of which my cause the error is that my site runs on HTTP (non-SSL) and the maps can't run on HTTP and needs HTTPS -> HTTP vs HTTPS.

I hope someone can help me solve this issue. Thanks!

**Update**: I've just noticed the problem only appears in Safari.

[Link to my site](http://checkspot.nl/appendo/website)

Answer (score 0):

I think the link to your site is not correct atm. At first sight the implementation code looks alright.

Comment: Updated the URL. Switched the parts after the first / in the wrong order. :-)

Comment: Nice website. I'm not very specialized in Safari specific behavior for  SLL. I found a [link](http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/19465/embedded-google-calendar-not-showing-up-on-safari) that looks like a similar issue. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and your compliment. I've read the topic, but that's sadly not relevant to my issue. Still thanks for your support! :)